# export HTTP_PROXY and special characters in passwd

Tags: bash, password, proxy, escape-characters

Suppose for the sake of argument my password below is `abc123@`

I need to authenticate my linux machine through a corporate proxy to get patches and updates... normally I'd use this:

```
export HTTP_PROXY='http://<Americas\Username>:<Password>@proxy.foo.com'
export http_proxy='http://<Americas\Username>:<Password>@proxy.foo.com'
```

However, when I substitute a real password ending with `@` and then run `aptitude update`, I get...

```
[mpenning@netwiki ~]$ sudo -E aptitude update
Err http://mirror.anl.gov squeeze Release.gpg
  Could not resolve '@proxy.foo.com'
Err http://mirror.anl.gov/debian/ squeeze/main Translation-en
  Could not resolve '@proxy.foo.com'
```

I have tried escaping the password with `\@`, escaping both with `\@\@`, double characters (`@@`), and nothing seems to get this to proxy correctly; I never had a problem until I changed my password recently.

What is the right way to escape my password in `bash`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could try [URL-encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) your password. `@` should be replaced by `%40`.

[Tackling Special Characters in Proxy Passwords on Linux](http://technodedigest.wordpress.com/2012/04/14/tackling-special-characters-in-proxy-passwords-on-linux/) indicates this should work, but looking around other people seem not to get that to work (and I have no way of testing this).

Comment: Just to save you time : http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/. Thanks for the tip @Mat

Answer (score 2):

**Even more simple and Reliable!**

**General Syntax:**

```
sudo {http,https,ftp}_proxy=http://<username>:<password>@<proxy_url/_proxyip>:<port>/ wget --timeout=5 --no-check-certificate http://<website_url>
```

**Example:**

```
[root@localhost ~]# sudo {http,https,ftp}_proxy=http://username:password-123@proxy.example.com:6050/ wget --timeout=5 --no-check-certificate http://google.com
```

**{http,https,ftp}_proxy**   -> http, https, ftp urls. Seperated by comma.

**--timeout=5**  -> Connection to keep alive in seconds.

**-no-check-certificate**  -> Ignore SSL / Certificate Verification.

**--spider**  -> If you want to test the connectivity without downloading the file.

**Notes:**

**Online Converter:**

Replace special characters with its equivalent hexadecimal unicode. 
For a list of unicodes refer the website [https://unicode-table.com](http://unicodelookup.com) (or) [http://unicodelookup.com](https://unicode-table.com)

**Local Converter using Python:**

**Reference:** conversion of password "p@s#w:E" to unicode will be as follows,

```
@ = %40
$ = %24
# = %23
: = %3A
p@s#w:E = p%40s%23w%3AE
```

**Input:**

```
[root@localhost ~]# python -c "import sys, urllib as enc; print enc.quote_plus(sys.argv[1])" "p@s#w:E"
```

**Output:**

```
p%40s%23w%3AE
```

Answer (score 0):

please use %40  in place of @ in your password,

for Example:

your password is "   A@ple123   "  then use " A%40ple123"